# What does "Inspire Loyalty" actually do?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm playing as a Zabrak, whose social ability is "Inspire Loyalty".  When I use it the target ally is either "Feeling patriotic" if it works or "Not feeling it" if it fails.  What does this "feeling" do for them?  Does it temporarily increase stats in any way, or have some other effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All racial abilities are purely social, they cause no interference in combat and do not affect stats in any way.